# Creating OD Cost (Time) Matrix for Points and Line Shape of Road using ArcGIS Pro and Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst

I am using the **OD cost matrix analysis layer** by referring here (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/od-cost-matrix-analysis-layer.htm).

I first import 70 points (shape file) as "origins" and "destinations."

Then, I would try to compute the travel time matrix for these 70 points (i.e., 70 x 70 = 4900 entries in the travel time matrix) along the historical road network in 1970.

The problem is that I want to use the **line shape** of the historical road network in 1970 as a network that a traveler can use (i.e., I do not allow any other network when computing travel time).

How can I set that in the OD matrix analysis layer?

Comment: If you are seeking a recommendation for alternative software to do this then there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Are you asking for the output you want to see the actual route taken along your network?

Comment: I would like to get the time matrix between all location pairs along my network (road).